# Implement set with insert complexity of o(k)

Tags: algorithm, set, time-complexity

One guy asked me a question what is the complexity of set insert.

I have given following answer. If number of elements is n.

1. O(n). If we implement set using array. Where n is number of elements.
2. O(log n ). If we implement using red-black tree.

But he told insert can be done with complexity of O(k). Where k is constant and which don't depend on size n.

According to me possible solution will be hash set. Which will be having complexity of O(1) and complexity will increase to max O(k)  on collision and if we have more than k collision we can increase the bucket size of hash function. But still it is most of time O(1).

Is there any other way to achieve insert in O(k) time ?

Comment: O(k) where k is constant is a bad way of saying O(1).

Comment: If more than k elements hash to the same value, increasing the size of the hash table won't help (I'm assuming that's what you mean by "increase the bucket size of hash function").

Comment: ya I know. @JBNizet So is there any other solution with O(k) complexity ?

Comment: I think you are missing some more information about `k`

Comment: Given a proper hashCode implementation, HashSet is O(1). Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Dukeling 
It may help. Let's take an example. In starting we have only 2 server. We hashed value 2, 4. H(2) = 0 and H(4) =0 . Now if change hash size to 3. H(2) = 2 , H(4) = 1 . They started moving to new values.

Comment: @VivekGoel In that case it will help, yes. But I'm actually talking about you have multiple hashed values of `2`, for example - regardless of the hash table size, they'll all hash to the same value (presumably `2 % size`). You'll have O(n) worst-case with a hash table, even though that's highly unlikely with a hash function appropriate for your data.

Comment: for certain kinds of elements a `java.util.BitSet` is another way to achieve O(1) time complexity.